# Carrierwave VPS symlinks not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, vps

I have setup [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) on a softlayer VPS.
Carrierwave gives an option to save files on local storage.

If I use symlink for `public/images` to `shared_path/images` then images gets uploaded but doesn't get rendered.
And when I remove the symlink and directly store images in `public/images`, then am able to see the images, but its of least use as the later release wont have those images.

My uploader class `app/uploader/image_uploader.rb` looks like this

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def default_url
    "/assets/default.gif"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def store_dir
    "images"
  end
end
```

I have used symlinks in my deploy scripts

```
    set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/images}

    desc "Symbolic Link for Uploads"
      task :symlink_uploads, :roles => [:app, :web] do
         run "rm -rf #{release_path}/public/images &&
              ln -nfs #{shared_path}/images  #{release_path}/public/images"
    end

    after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_uploads'
```

Tried setting permissions too. But still I don't see my uploaded images.

I get following message when I try to access images from browser

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /images/my_profile.jpg on this server.
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80
```

Have also searched through
[Capistrano and Carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586548/capistrano-and-carrierwave),
[Carrierwave files with Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043662/carrierwave-files-with-capistrano)

Do I need to set specific permissions for the directories to be accessible ?
for example:

```
chmod 755 shared_path/images
```

Unable to find any working solution on it.
Highly appreciate a help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, this was missing

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

[apache permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936549/apache-permissions-error)

Though I had `Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks MultiViews` under

`<Directory></Directory>`

Wondering why `+FollowSymLinks` wasn't working